# Do we have hold elections for moderators here?

Tags: discussion, moderation

At Stackoverflow, they are holding moderator elections, how often do we do that here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As a beta site, three moderators were nominated Pro Tem by SE staff.

When we graduate, real elections will be held. [Graduation criteria can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). The long and short is we need to average 10 questions a day to graduate.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: Are you saying if I can come up with 3 questions everyday we graduate? The number has been going up the last two years, so there is hope :) Already 2025 days in beta...

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal In a sense, yes. They look at many things, but the whole process really starts rolling once there's 10 questions per day.